# Anypoint Studio - DataWeave 1.0 - How to add comments?

Tags: comments, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mule-esb

Is it possible to add comments to our DataWeave v1.0 scripts in Anypoint Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can add a single-line comment:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%namespace ns0 http://www.namespace.com/resource
---
{   
    // This is a comment.
    id: payload.id
}
```

But be careful: comments are not allowed everywhere. For example; comments at the end of the file won't work at the moment.

See also the related topic in the MuleSoft forum: [Comments in DataWeave](https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/33295/comments-in-dataweave.html)